# Java-Increment date for every occurance of second field

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

We wrote a Java code to increment the input time by 30 mins.
But this is incrementing the input time once and applying the same value.
This program gets two inputs one will be initial date and second is count of records. If we got 20 as count of records. The code should populate 20 intervals of time incremented by 30 mins from start time in an array

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");

Date date = new Date  () ;

try
{
     date = ( Date )formatter.parse(var1);
}

catch ( ParseException  e){}

Calendar clndr = Calendar.getInstance();

clndr.setTime(date);

clndr.add(clndr.MINUTE, 30);

date = clndr.getTime();

String strDate = formatter.format(date);

return strDate;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question: as it is, it is barely intelligible.  What do you mean by : "Lets say the second input field has appeared thrice then the first field time should increment thrice like 30 mins 1 hour and 1:30hour."?  What do you mean by "fields"?

Comment: Sorry. This program gets two inputs one will be initial date and second is count of records. If we got 20 as count of records. The code should populate 20 intervals of time incremented by 30 mins from start time in an array

Answer (score 0):

Pass your second input field in method and multiply it by "30"

so in place of 30 you should get "30*secondfield" input

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, what you want is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String initial = "2013-01-16-10.06.02";

    String after30 = increment(initial);
    System.out.println(after30);

    after30 = increment(after30);
    System.out.println(after30);

    after30 = increment(after30);
    System.out.println(after30);

}

public static String increment(String var1) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");

    Date date = new Date();

    try

    {

        date = (Date) formatter.parse(var1);

    }

    catch (ParseException e) {}

    Calendar clndr = Calendar.getInstance();

    clndr.setTime(date);

    clndr.add(clndr.MINUTE, 30);

    date = clndr.getTime();

    String strDate = formatter.format(date);

    return strDate;
}
```

Note that you must use the return of the method as input for subsequent calls.

In time, I wouldn't use the try-catch as you stated. I'd put a throws clause in method...

[]s